# Array is not being updated via onChange handler in reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, input

I am trying to add each value entered in separate input element which is added on clicking "add" button on GUI, into an array.

There is no initial array, so please do not suggest putting index from any mapping of initial array.

Multiple input elements are added when user clicks on add button on GUI, the method subDivs() below explains that.

So I am passing counter value as an index in onChange handler, but this code does not work. Really looking for some productive inputs, maybe I am missing some essential part.

```
  handleChange(event, index) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let { nameArray } = this.state;
    nameArray[index] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({nameArray}, () => console.log("Array ", nameArray))
  }

addRow() {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
  };

  subDivs() {
    let count = this.state.count, uiItems = [];
    var { names } = this.state;
    let options2 = names.map(name2 => {
      return { value: name2.name, label: name2.name };
    })
    while (count--)
      uiItems.push(
        <div className="newName" key={this.nextUniqueId()}>
          <div className="input-group mb-3" >
            <input id={count+1} type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name"
              onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, count+1)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    return uiItems;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be helpful.

```js
handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let { nameArray } = this.state;
    if (!Array.isArray(nameArray)) nameArray = [];
    nameArray.push(event.target.value);
    this.setState({nameArray}, () => {
      return {
        nameArray
      };
    });
  }
```

Comment: This solution does work, but I get each letter typed and added as a separate element in an array like below, how can I just get the final value typed such as "Test" and "Name"

Comment: ```
Array [ "T" ]
Array [ "T", "Te" ]
Array(3) [ "T", "Te", "Tes" ] 
Array(4) [ "T", "Te", "Tes", "Test" ]
Array(5) [ "T", "Te", "Tes", "Test", "N" ]
Array(6) [ "T", "Te", "Tes", "Test", "N", "Na" ]
Array(7) [ "T", "Te", "Tes", "Test", "N", "Na", "Nam" ]
Array(8) [ "T", "Te", "Tes", "Test", "N", "Na", "Nam", "Name" ]

Comment: There might be some event rather than onChange on which you are confirmed that this is the name that I want to add. Just call the above method on that event.

Comment: Like this :  onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeHN(e)}

Comment: do you mean I should create one method, which captures the current value and the other which adds that value in an array?

Comment: Yes... Create a method that captures the value and inside `addRow`, you can add your value to the state.